# Pass value to method by object type union

Tags: typescript, api, oop

I have a class for processing data and the data could be from different sources. I need to pass the source from where the data should be fetch. So, I want to ask, what is the proper way to do it:

- create an object of defined interface which could be extended and probably more clear to developer - **processDataA**
- pass all in one variable and check the source by type of variable - less code and not so complicated - **processDataB**
- use of separate variables of the method is not a case - I need to pass this value through lot of classes/options into target class

Example:

```
interface DataProviderSource {
   dataURL?: string;
   dataArchive?: ArrayBuffer;
}

processDataA(source: DataProviderSource) {
   if (source.dataURL) {
      ...
   } else if (source.dataArchive) {
      ...
   } else {
      ...
   }
}

processDataB(source: ArrayBuffer | string) {
   if (source instanceof ArrayBuffer) {
      ...
   } else if (typeof source === "string") {
      ...
   } else {
     ...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing to avoid is having *weak interfaces* like this one:

```
interface DataProviderSource {
   dataURL?: string;
   dataArchive?: ArrayBuffer;
}
```

because — since every property is optional — it allows an empty object to be passed. We don't want that — we want exactly one format of the data to be passed.

It is a matter of taste. One way to go would be:

```
class Processor {
  static fromArrayBuffer(source: ArrayBuffer) {}
  static fromString(source: string) {}

  process(source: string | ArrayBuffer) {
    if (source instanceof ArrayBuffer) {
      return Processor.fromArrayBuffer(source);
    }

    return Processor.fromString(source);
  }
}
```

It's simple, but it breaks the open/closed principle. You can also model your sources with named constructors. In this design, each type of source is equipped with its own processor.

```
interface Source<T = any> {
    data: T;
    process: () => void;
}

class DataURL implements Source<string> {
    constructor(readonly data: string) {
        this.data = data;
    };

    process() {}
}

class Archieve implements Source<ArrayBuffer> {
    constructor(readonly data: ArrayBuffer) {
        this.data = data;
    };

    process() {}
}

class SomeOther implements Source<string> {
    constructor(readonly data: string) {
        this.data = data;
    };

    process() {}
}
```

This solution is open for extension. The only thing that matters is for the source to implement the `Source` interface.

```
const process = (...sources: Source[]): void =>
  sources.forEach(source => source.process())

process(
    new DataURL('hello'),
    new Archieve(new ArrayBuffer(32)),
    new SomeOther('world')
);
```

Comment: I see. It looks like **processDataB** in my post. But in this case I'm wondering about extendibility of this code. What if I would need to add third source which is also string. For example: **dataLocalPath** or **dataDBConnectionString**

Comment: Yes, it is a naïve solution. I added one that doesn't break the open/closed principle.

Comment: Thanks for answer! But I still have doubts. What if I have to provide some input into factory function and the factory has decide which class should be used (DataURL/Archieve/SomeOther)?